# What is the relationship between the product function and the concept of permutations with repetitions?

Tags: python

```
from itertools import permutations,product,combinations_with_replacement

colours = ['r','g','b']

y = list(product(colours,repeat =2 ))
x = list(combinations_with_replacement(colours,2))
print(y)
print(x)
```

I understand permutation of a set of objects is an ordering of those objects. When some of those objects are identical, the situation is transformed into permutations with repetition.

Comment: What do you mean by relationship here? Do you mean  - an explanation of how they are similar vs different or do you mean a mathematical relationship of some kind?

Comment: I would like the explanation

Comment: Did you try looking at the output? Did you see how the outputs are different? Can you see a pattern in what is different? Did you try reading the documentation? I can't understand how there is an actual question here.

Comment: Hint: do you understand the difference between permutations and combinations in the first place? Do you understand what replacement means in this context? Then - "product" is the same thing as "permutations with replacement". Is that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may provide some insight:

```py
colours = ['r','g','b']

y = list(product(colours,repeat =2 ))
x = list(combinations_with_replacement(colours,2))
z = [v for v in y if colours.index(v[0]) <= colours.index(v[1])]
print(y)
print(x)
print(z)
```

Output:

```
[('r', 'r'), ('r', 'g'), ('r', 'b'), ('g', 'r'), ('g', 'g'), ('g', 'b'), ('b', 'r'), ('b', 'g'), ('b', 'b')]
[('r', 'r'), ('r', 'g'), ('r', 'b'), ('g', 'g'), ('g', 'b'), ('b', 'b')]
[('r', 'r'), ('r', 'g'), ('r', 'b'), ('g', 'g'), ('g', 'b'), ('b', 'b')]
```

In other words, `product` provides all possible sequences with repetition, whereas `combinations_with_replacement` will (in your example) consider `g, b` and `b, g` to be equivalent and includes only `g, b`.

We can replicate `combinations_with_replacement` by filtering out equivalent  permutations from `product`, as is done with `z` above.